Solving $f'(x) = -g(x)/x$, $g'(x) = f(x)/x$
Find all differentiable functions $f$ and $g$ at $(0,∞)$ such that $f'(x) = -g(x)/x$ and $g'(x) = f(x)/x$ for all $x > 0$.
I tried to determine the second derivative of  $f$, then substituted $g(x)$ and $g'(x)$ to $f''(x)$. In the end, I obtained the Cauchy-Euler equation. Is this method correct? Is there any other way to answer this question?
Could you please help me? How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

I have made the title more specific.

Hint: Substitute $x=e^u$.

@MartinR, Where should I substitute $x=e^u$? Do I need to determine the second derivative of one of the functions (f or g), so that the form of the Cauchy Euler equation appears?

Transforming the system to a Cauchy–Euler equation is a possible approach:
$$
 f(x) = x g'(x) = x (-x f'(x))' = -x f'(x) - x^2 f''(x) \\
\implies x^2 f''(x) + x f'(x) + f(x) = 0 \, .
$$
That is a Cauchy–Euler equation with the characteristic equation $m^2+1 = 0$, which has the complex roots $m = \pm i$. In that case (“Case 3” in the Wikipedia article) the solutions are
$$
 f(x) = c_1 x^\alpha \cos(\beta \ln(x)) + c_2 x^\alpha \sin(\beta \ln(x))
$$
with $\alpha = \operatorname{Re}(m) = 0$ and $\beta = \operatorname{Im}(m) = 1$, i.e.
$$
 f(x) = c_1 \cos(\ln(x)) + c_2 \sin(\ln(x))
$$
with $c_1, c_2 \in \Bbb R$. The corresponding solution $g$ is then determined by
$$
g(x) = - x f'(x) = c_1 \sin(\ln(x)) - c_2 \cos(\ln(x)) \, .
$$

As mentioned in the Wikipedia article, this form of the solution is derived by setting $x = e^t$, and this can already be done with the original equations: The functions
$$
 F(t) = f(e^t) \, , \, G(t) =g(e^t)
$$
satisfy
$$
 F'(t) = -G(t) \, , \, G'(t) = F(t) \, .
$$
Then $F''(t) + F(t) = 0$, which has the well-known solutions
$$
 F(t) = c_1 \cos(t) + c_2 \sin(t) \, , \\
 G(t) = c_1 \sin(t) - c_2 \cos(t) \, ,
$$
and $f(x) = F(\ln(x))$ , $g(x) = G(\ln(x))$ are the solutions of the original system.

Sorry, i want to ask how to get $x(−xf(x))′$ from $xg′(x)$?

@mathstudent: Sorry, there was a typo. It should be correct now.

okay, thank you

Dividing the two equations, we get
$$ \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = -\frac{g(x)}{f(x)} $$
or, $$\int f(x)f'(x)dx+\int g(x)g'(x)dx = 0$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{(f(x))^2}{2}+\frac{(g(x))^2}{2}=C_{1}$$ $$\Rightarrow f(x) = \sqrt{C_{1} - (g(x))^2} $$
Substituting in the second equation yeilds $$ g'(x) = \frac{\sqrt{C_{1} - (g(x))^2}}{x}$$ $$\Rightarrow \int \frac{g'(x)}{\sqrt{C_{1} - (g(x))^2}} dx = \int \frac{1}{x}dx $$
Or $$\arcsin \left(\frac{g(x)}{\sqrt{C_{1}}} \right) = C_{2} + \log(x)$$
Giving the solutions
$$\boxed{g(x) = K \cdot \sin(C_{2} + \log(x))}$$
$$\boxed{f(x)= K \cdot \cos(C_{2} + \log(x))}$$

$C_2$ shouldn't be multiplying $\log x$.

edited, I'm sorry, haven't slept

Before you go to bed, in place of $\sqrt{C_1}$ you can put any multiplicative constant, negative in particular.

Set $f(x)=F(\ln x)$ and $g(x)=G(\ln x).$ The given identities then become
$$
F'(\ln x)\frac1x = -\frac{G(\ln x)}{x},\quad
G'(\ln x)\frac1x = \frac{F(\ln x)}{x},
$$
i.e.
$$
F'(t) = -G(t),\quad G'(t) = F(t).
$$
The solutions are
$$
F(t) = A\cos t + B\sin t,\quad G(t) = -B\cos t + A\sin t,
$$
i.e.
$$
f(x) = A\cos(\ln x) + B\sin(\ln x),\quad g(x) = -B\cos(\ln x) + A\sin(\ln x).
$$
